# Is Agasthya Smriti containing the Original Chess Strategy available in public Domain?

Tags: history, books

Saint Agasthya was the most knowledgeable person of the 8000 yrs ago period. He is credited for:

1. The Martial Arts (Kalari Paytu),
2. Chemical based Medicines specially for Venom treatment,
3. Game of Chess called "Shad Yantra" of 100 Squares,
4. Beautifully written Tamil Script and Language,
5. Got Entire Land of Sri Lanka given to him by MahaBali, as Vaman (Dwarf) Avtar.

It is said that Agasthya Smriti (Memoirs of Agasthya) has summary of his all inventions and actions, including Agasthya Suktam. Agasthya Suktam is said to be a chapter about how to manage WAR and play Chess Game with pieces.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is in the public domain, assuming you can find a copy of it online or in a library. His works are from many years ago, if what you say is accurate. Copyright law simply does not apply.

Comment: Can you share the link or point me in some direction? I have created the demo game of ShadYantra Chess and revived this game online. The next challenge is to make the demo game of ShatRanjan which is more complex game which was modified by Chanakya(Kautilya).

Comment: @ShadYantra My answer has no sources. I merely used logic to answer the legalese in your question as I see it. If I am wrong, please edit your question-especially the title.

Comment: @ShadYantra Do you perhaps mean this one? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agastya_Samhita That would give you immediate links. (Wiki mentions no work "Smriti" in the main article about Agastya.)

Comment: Agastya Samhita is collection of Agasthya and still not complete and other scrolls or manuscripts still are not discovered.

Comment: @ShadYantra And it may never be complete, given history happens, so what you can get may be the best answer.

Comment: I have seen miracles happening in my life. This has made me spiritual . The first question which I raise to my mind is why I was chosen by destiny to work on it...  Surya Siddhant is also very trickier which world has not yet understood.